# See which item is calling a form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am currently trying to program a version of mastermind. I use oval shapes for the pins and I have it set up that when you click an oval it shows form2 containing the color selection. I am looking for some kind of code that will make it possible to see which oval was clicked and use that to get the selected color to the right oval. I know I could do it by adding a form for each oval I have, but I think there has to be a better solution out there :)

Code:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
Public Class Form1
Dim pc1 As Integer
Dim pc2 As Integer
Dim pc3 As Integer
Dim pc4 As Integer
Public Shared frmMain As Form1

Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    frmMain = Me
    Randomize()
    pc1 = Math.Round(Rnd() * 5) + 1

    pc2 = Math.Round(Rnd() * 5) + 1
    While pc2 = pc1
        pc2 = Math.Round(Rnd() * 5) + 1
    End While

    pc3 = Math.Round(Rnd() * 5) + 1
    While pc3 = pc1 Or pc3 = pc2
        pc3 = Math.Round(Rnd() * 5) + 1
    End While

    pc4 = Math.Round(Rnd() * 5) + 1
    While pc4 = pc1 Or pc4 = pc2 Or pc4 = pc3
        pc4 = Math.Round(Rnd() * 5) + 1
    End While

    showpc()
End Sub
Sub showpc()
    If pc1 = 1 Then
        OvalShape41.BackColor = Color.Blue
    ElseIf pc1 = 2 Then
        OvalShape41.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf pc1 = 3 Then
        OvalShape41.BackColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf pc1 = 4 Then
        OvalShape41.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf pc1 = 5 Then
        OvalShape41.BackColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf pc1 = 6 Then
        OvalShape41.BackColor = Color.White
    End If
    If pc2 = 1 Then
        OvalShape42.BackColor = Color.Blue
    ElseIf pc2 = 2 Then
        OvalShape42.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf pc2 = 3 Then
        OvalShape42.BackColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf pc2 = 4 Then
        OvalShape42.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf pc2 = 5 Then
        OvalShape42.BackColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf pc2 = 6 Then
        OvalShape42.BackColor = Color.White
    End If
    If pc3 = 1 Then
        OvalShape43.BackColor = Color.Blue
    ElseIf pc3 = 2 Then
        OvalShape43.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf pc3 = 3 Then
        OvalShape43.BackColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf pc3 = 4 Then
        OvalShape43.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf pc3 = 5 Then
        OvalShape43.BackColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf pc3 = 6 Then
        OvalShape43.BackColor = Color.White
    End If
    If pc4 = 1 Then
        OvalShape44.BackColor = Color.Blue
    ElseIf pc4 = 2 Then
        OvalShape44.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf pc4 = 3 Then
        OvalShape44.BackColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf pc4 = 4 Then
        OvalShape44.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf pc4 = 5 Then
        OvalShape44.BackColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf pc4 = 6 Then
        OvalShape44.BackColor = Color.White
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OvalShape1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles OvalShape1.Click, OvalShape2.Click, OvalShape3.Click, OvalShape4.Click
    ' delete all the other click events or remark them out

    ' sender is still whichever OVal was clicked:

    Dim oval As OvalShape = sender

    ' FORM1 is not correct, need the instance name
    Me.OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.FromName(oval.Tag)
End Sub
End Class
Public Class Form2

Private Sub OvalShape1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OvalShape1.Click
    Form1.OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.Blue
End Sub

Private Sub OvalShape2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OvalShape2.Click
    Form1.OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.Red

End Sub

Private Sub OvalShape3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OvalShape3.Click
    Form1.OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.Lime

End Sub

Private Sub OvalShape4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OvalShape4.Click
    Form1.OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.Yellow

End Sub

Private Sub OvalShape5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OvalShape5.Click
    Form1.OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.Black

End Sub

Private Sub OvalShape6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OvalShape6.Click
    Form1.OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.White

End Sub
End Class
```

It is far from complete, this is just something I ran into, probably it can be made much more compact but I will look into that when it's finished :)

Comment: that is avaailble in the click event.  what is the oval drawn on?...code to see what you are doing would help too

Comment: what is "IT" what kind of control is the oval drawn on?

Comment: How are you calling Form2 ? I probably would give it a public property and set it in your click event handler

Comment: `sender` is going to tell you which one was clicked, in fact it IS the one that was clicked

Comment: your ovals are controls, sender is the control (OVAL) that you clicked and it shows up in the param list for alllll those click events

Answer (score 3):

EDIT
Here is one way to collapse all that code in form2:

The OValShape probably has a property named TAG, set the ones on **Form2** to 'Blue', 'Red' etc.  Then:

```
Private Sub OvalShape1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
     Handles OvalShape1.Click, OvalShape2.Click, _
     'Handles OvalShape3.Click ... (add a handles clause for each oval, 
     '     ' delete all the other click events or remark them out

 ' sender is still whichever OVal was clicked:

 Dim oval as OvalShape = Sender

 ' FORM1 is not correct, need the instance name
 frmOther.OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.FromName(oval.Tag)

End Sub
```

EDIT

Assuming you app starts from a FormMain which is Form1, we needs to make a public reference for it.  In Form1:

```
Public Shared frmMain As Form1
```

In your FormLoad event:

```
Sub Form_Load (......) handles Me.Load
   frmMain = Me
End Sub
```

Now, Form2 code will use frmMain as the instance reference.

EDIT 3

This is Mark's idea: instead of Form2 messing with form1's toys, we will expose a property for Form1 to set the color himself.  In Form2:

```
Public SelectedColor As Color

' slight change here
Private Sub OvalShape1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
      Handles OvalShape1.Click, Handles OvalShape2.Click
      ' add a HANDLES for each Oval click event so you dont have to 
      ' copy this code to all of them, but DELETE the old ones.
      ' your code looks like you added the multiple HAndles to that click (prematurely)


 ' sender is still whichever OVal was clicked:

 Dim oval as OvalShape = Sender
 SelectedColor =  Color.FromName(oval.Tag)

 Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
 me.Close


End Sub
```

In Form1:

```
Private Sub OvalShape1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OvalShape1.Click
       'sender is the oval shape clicked, so
   dim oval As OvalShape = sender
   dim oClr as Color = oval.BackColor

   ' Form2 is a CLASS or a template for a form...need to make an instance
   ' of Form2 to show:

   dim frm as New Form2(oClr)             ' the right way

   ' kind of pointless since we only return OK
   if frm.ShowDialog=DialogResult.Ok then

      OvalShape1.BackColor = frm.SelectedColor        ' get the color selected
   end if


End Sub
```

Comment: @Plutonix it looks like Form2 needs to return a Color, Passing the color in the constructor is fine, but I would use ShowDialog like you suggest but check for a DialogResult and pass the selected color back in a Property or a Function, I dislike setting a forms controls from another form.

Comment: @MarkHall  yes, I think I misread the specs and am passing it the wrong way...I thought Form2 needed it, but I cant see how/where it would be used.  I read your comment more carefeully, Yes!  I get it now!  Need to get form2 to show first

Comment: edit your post to show the procedure (click event) which shows form2, please and delete some comments at the top

Comment: @Plutonix my guess is that he is using the color to show in form2, what color the oval in form1 is, and then setting form1's oval by what he selects in Form2. Passing the color in the constructor is fine I was talking about the return value. Coding access to Form1's controls ties form2 to tightly to form1

Comment: @MarkHall, I agree, I dont think Form2 needs that arg (I got confused).  A property will work fine once we get form2 to show

Comment: It gives an error for oClr it says Too many arguments to Public sub new and when I do generate method stub it runs but form2 appears empty